# How to enforce time limits on Mac with a password?

Tags: macos, mac, parental-controls

I'd like to set time limits for when applications can be used on my Mac using the system parental controls.

I went into screen time and set rules for when all applications could be used and then I set the password.

I'm also not the administrator for this computer, so I do not actually know the password for screen time.

But, when it's passed the time I set, all I have to do to use the apps is click "ignore for 15 minutes."

How do I actually enforce the time limits on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, if you're an adult, your Screen Time settings are controlled by you.  Try setting a Screen Time passcode.  Then, at least, you'll be prompted to enter the passcode to continue using apps during a lockdown period.

If you're a minor and part of a Family (in Apple/iCloud terms) one of the adults in the Family needs to set the passcode (for your acct) from their device.